# In Rails- how do you get the distinct rows from X column and from that sum Y column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, distinct

I have a model view controller in my rails app, which pulls in user entered data from the view and places it into a table in the database. The table named "table" that looks like this:

```
__X__|__Y__|__Created_At__
  A  |  1  |  2021-01-02
  B  |  5  |  2021-01-02
  C  |  3  |  2021-01-02
  A  |  4  |  2021-01-01
```

What I need is a function to find the unique values in the X column of the table (i.e. a singular A, B, C... in order of the most recently entered value... so in this case the value I'd want pulled for A would be the first one there since it was created most recently), then it needs to take those unique valued rows and pull the Y values and sum them together.

This is what I was trying but it didn't work:

```
Table.distinct(:x).sum(:y)
```

The issue is that seems to just be summing all values in Y, instead of disregarding the bottom duplicate A.

If it makes any difference I'm using Rails 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding this perfectly: you have a Table model with an X:string column. You want to get all instances of Table
`Table.all`
and return an array of them
`Table.all.collect {|x| x }`
You then want to sort them by created_at
`Table.all.collect {|x| x }.sort_by{|x| x.created_at}`
and keep the most recent ones. This should do everything so far:

```
Table.all.collect {|x| x }.sort_by{|x| x.created_at}.uniq
```

What do you mean by "take these unique valued rows and pull the Y values and sum them together"? Sum all the Y values? Or sum the Xs and the Ys? Are the X integers to be added?

Comment: Hi Grimhamr, thank you for your response! What I meant was that I need it to sum column Y after removing all rows that have duplicate values in column X (so it would remove all of the older duplicate rows and only keep the newest). So for example in the table above, I need it to remove the second A row from the equation. So the sum would only include 1, 5, and 3. So the result would be 9.

Comment: @jdk okay, in that case the `Table.all.collect {|x| x }.sort_by{|x| x.created_at}.uniq` line should give you all the X-unique instances of Table. You should then be able to do: `Table.all.collect {|x| x }.sort_by{|x| x.created_at}.uniq.collect {|x| x.y}.sum` and sum them all together if I'm understanding this right

Comment: Thank you! That calculation is still giving the same number as the one I tried though (i.e. 1+5+3+4 = 13). I'm not sure why it won't drop the last value. Is there anything that could be causing that?

Comment: This should give all the unique, latest Xs: `unique_x = Table.all.collect {|x| x }.sort_by{|x| x.created_at}.uniq`
You should be able to get the unique, latest rows by using `Table.where(X: unique_x})`. Does that work? Sorry for the confusion, but the table and column names are frying my brain

Comment: can you update your question explaining what you want (e.g. "So for example in the table above, I need it to remove the second A row from the equation. So the sum would only include 1, 5, and 3. So the result would be 9.") ? As written it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Also what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgres it supports "distinct on" which makes it relatively easy to do this directly in the database. That would look like:

```
SELECT SUM(distinct_on_x.Y) 
FROM (
  SELECT distinct ON (X) Y 
  FROM table 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
) AS distinct_on_x
```

You can execute this directly with `select_values`, something like:

```
select_distinct_count_sql = <<-SQL
SELECT SUM(distinct_on_x.Y) 
FROM (
  SELECT distinct ON (X) Y 
  FROM table 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
) AS distinct_on_x
SQL
Table.connection.select_values(select_distinct_count_sql)
```

If you just want the distinct rows so you can sum them in memory you can do:

```
Table.select("DISTINCT ON (X) *").order("X, created_at")
```